# Select label to always cover the component even despite there being a selected value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI v5 with emotion, and need the label of the component to always cover the select whether there is/are selected values or not.

After checking their docs and google search, it seems there is no easy way for this.

Here is a basic example from the docs.
https://codesandbox.io/s/up080d?file=/demo.tsx

At first as you can see the label "Age" covers all of the select box. Once click the label goes on top, and once a value is selected the label is staying always on top. What I need is for the label to behave as if there was no value selected, still covering the whole select box after the selection is done.

Did anyone achieved this before, or any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? And explain in a bit more detail what the issue is you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work with the following:

```js
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label" shrink={false}>
          {!age && "Age"}
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-placeholder-select-behavior-npt4mh?file=/demo.tsx:519-1101)